# Spring CrudRepository - validate before save in JSF project

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I can't figure out why validation errors raise instead of beign just displayed after submitting a form ? I'm using HIbernate, Spring and JSF. I declared validation as of JSR 303 and use Hibernate annotation as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "title")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Title should not be empty")
    private String title;
... other fields are ommited
}
```

In the corresponding bean I'm trying to save a post as follows:

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@URLMappings(mappings = {
        @URLMapping(id = "posts", pattern = "/posts/", viewId = "/faces/posts/list.xhtml"),
        @URLMapping(id = "new", pattern = "/posts/new", viewId = "/faces/posts/new.xhtml")
})
public class PostBean {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    private List<Post> posts;

    private Post post = new Post();

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return postService.findAll();
    }

    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(Post post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

    public String create(Post post) {
        postService.save(post);
        return "pretty:posts";
    }
....
}
```

The Post related repository is declared as follows:

```
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {
    public Post findByTitleIgnoreCase(String title);
}
```

When submitting a form I get the below error:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.airial.domain.Post] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Title should not be empty', propertyPath=title, rootBeanClass=class com.airial.domain.Post, messageTemplate='Title should not be empty'}
]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.airial.domain.Post] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Title should not be empty', propertyPath=title, rootBeanClass=class com.airial.domain.Post, messageTemplate='Title should not be empty'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
```

Any idea on how to fix it, i.e. to run validation before save ?

You can find the projet at github repo: https://github.com/Javix/blog-jsf.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried the `@NotNull` annotation in your `title` field instead?

Comment: Just tried it, no difference. What is strange is that if I use Faces validation tag and put required="true" aside of the title textfiled in the view, then add the below config into web.xml:<context-param>
        <param-name>
            javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL
        </param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>, and remove anotation from the POst model, it works.